# Are there any way to make implementation for abstract class which is multiple inheriting from other abstract classes in c++?

Tags: c++, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

I have two 'interface' classes : `AbstractAccess` and `AbstractPrint`, and `AbstractRun` class inheriting from them and using their methods.
Also, I have two implementation of interfaces: Accessor for `AbstractAccess` and Print for `AbstractPrint`

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                

using namespace std;                                                                                                                                                                                               

class AbstractAccess {                                                                                                                                                                                             
    public:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    virtual string access (void) = 0;                                                                                                                                                                              
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

class AbstractPrint {                                                                                                                                                                                              
    public:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    virtual void print (string) = 0;                                                                                                                                                                               
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

class AbstractRun : virtual public AbstractAccess, virtual public AbstractPrint {                                                                                                                                  
    public:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        void run (void) {                                                                                                                                                                                          
            print(access());                                                                                                                                                                                       
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                          
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

class Accessor : virtual public AbstractAccess {                                                                                                                                                                   
    public:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        string access (void){                                                                                                                                                                                      
            return name;                                                                                                                                                                                           
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                          

            void setName(string name) {                                                                                                                                                                                
            this->name = name;                                                                                                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                          

    private:                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        string name;                                                                                                                                                                                               
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

class Print: public virtual AbstractPrint {                                                                                                                                                                        
    public:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        void print (string s) {                                                                                                                                                                                    
            cout << s << endl;                                                                                                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                          
};
```

Are there any ways to cast interfaces in `AbstractRun` to their implementations or to create implementation class Run that will only use AbstractRun's 'run' method but with implemented interfaces?

Comment: I don't understand the first part either, but the second part (if I understand it correctly) is straightforward: `class Run: public virtual AbstractRun, public virtual Accessor, public virtual Print {...}`

Comment: @Beta Thank you so much. You' ve understood correctly and your recipe works like a charm. The first part doesn't needed if the second one is working. Thank you ome more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you already had your problem solved, I looked further into this and I would like to straighten some confusion about the inheritance.

Inheritance is used when your a class has a "is a" relationship with another class. The derived class should be a replacement for the class you are inheriting from.

In your case, you can safely say `class Print` is a `class AbstractPrint` and `class Access` likewise a `class AbstractPrint`, thus inheritance is fine here.

On the other hand, `class AbstractRun` is *not* a `AbstractPrint` and neither a `AbstractAccess`. `AbstractRun` simply handles / combines a `AbstractPrint`and `AbstractAccess`. This relationship should be abstracted with aggregation (or composition), in that `AbstractRun` *has* a reference/pointer to a `AbstractRun` and a `AbstractPrint`. This would make `AbstractRun` concrete, so let's rename it to `Runner`.

```
class Runner
{
public:

    // We now need a constructor to set the references.
    Runner(AbstractAccess& access, AbstractPrint& print) : 
    accessor(access), printer(print) {}

    void run (void) {
        printer.print(accessor.access());          
    }

private:
    AbstractAccess& accessor; // has a AbstractAccess
    AbstractPrint& printer;   // has a AbstractPrint 
};
```

Now `Access` and `Print` could be defined as before.

But let's improve those as well:

```
class Print: public virtual AbstractPrint {
    public:
        void print (string s) {                                                                                                                                                                                    
            cout << s << endl;                                                                                                                                                                                     
        }
};
```

We do not *need* virtual inheritance. Virtual inheritance is used to solve the diamond problem. But there is no diamond anymore than AbstractRunner was made a concrete class. So lets remove the unnecessary qualifiers.

```
class Accessor : public AbstractAccess {
    public:
        string access (void){
            return name;
        }

        void setName(string name) {
            this->name = name;
        }
    private:
        string name;
}; 

class Print: public AbstractPrint {
    public:
        void print (string s) {                                                                                                                                                                                    
            cout << s << endl;                                                                                                                                                                                     
        }
};
```

Furthermore, if you have a C++11 compatible compiler, I would suggest you to add the `override` qualifier for the methods that override a base function to be able to destinguish the methods that are taken from base class and not.

```
class Accessor : public AbstractAccess {
    public:
        string access (void) override { //overrides  AbstractAcces method
            return name;
        }

        void setName(string name) { //does not override. is a method at Accessor level
            this->name = name;
        }
    private:
        string name;
};
```

Now when initializing a `Runner`, we need to pass the concrete accessors and printers. This can be done as:

```
// Somewhere in a .cpp - file

Accessor accessor;
Print printer;

Runner runner(accessor, printe);

runner.run(); //will call printer and accessor through the references.
```